# C program trying to modify a location in text segment

Tags: c, linux

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[]="somethingisbetterthannothing";
    memset(str,'-',6);
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting a segmentation fault when this program is executed .
But it printed

```
------ingisbetterthannothing
```

Does this indicate that the string literal is not stored in read only text segment?

Comment: char str[]="string" ---> this is copied to stack but char *ptr="string" this is in RO  section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char str[]="somethingisbetterthannothing";
```

There is no string literal in the above line.
There is only an initializer for a `char`-array.

```
char* str = "somethingisbetterthannothing";
```

That would be a pointer to a string-literal.
And there is no guarantee what happens when you try to modify a string literal.
It is literally and explicitly [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984) (BTW: The example in the accepted answer is modifying a string-literal).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have the question : Till the function gets executed , where the string "sometingisbetterthannothing" will be kept in program file?

Comment: @whitetiger Anywhere convenient. Code, data, read-only-data. For such a long initializer, it will probably be handled like a string-literal. It might even be optimized out under the as-if rule.

Answer (score 1):

When strings are declared as character arrays, they are stored like other types of arrays in C.

For eg if str[] is an auto variable then string is stored in `stack segment`, if it’s a global or static variable then stored in `data segment`.

Using character pointer strings can be stored in two ways:

---> Read only string in a shared segment.
When string value is directly assigned to a pointer, in most of the compilers, it’s stored in a read only block (generally in data segment) that is shared among functions.

`char *str  =  "vinay";`

"vinay" is stored in a shared `read only location`, but pointer `str` is stored in a `read-write memory`

--> dynamic allocation using malloc

If you try to modify string literals or constants segmentation fault will get since change of RO section not allowed. But in your case you changing WR section i.e stack section so obviuolsy no error